# Сортировка сложных структур методом пузырька

Tags: c++, сортировка, структуры

Есть ли возможность сортировать записи в файле, сравнивая отдельное поле структуры типа char пузырьковой сортировкой? Если да, то как? Скажите пожалуйста алгоритм.

Код:

```
int main()
{
    dataBase* db = new dataBase[N];  //создание динамического массива db
    ReadBase(db);       

    for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        cout << db[i].name << "\t" << db[i].sumContribution << "\t" 
             << db[i].date << "\t" << db[i].advocate << endl ;      

    }   
    cout 
      << "_______________________________________________________________________________" 
      << "\n" << endl ;

    int temp;       
    for (int i=0; i<N-1; i++) 
    {
        for (int j=0; j<N-1; j++)
            if (db[j].name > db[j+1].name) 
            {
                temp = db[j];
                db[j].name = db[j+1].name;
                db[j+1].name = temp;
            }
    }   

    for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        cout << db[i].name << "\t" << db[i].sumContribution << "\t" 
             << db[i].date << "\t" << db[i].advocate << endl ;
    }
    delete[] db;    
    getch();
    return 0;   
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Конечно, можно. Но есть пару но.

Вы пе описали свой тип `dataBase`. Ну, будем надеяться, что поле `name` в нем имеет тип `string`, иначе сравнение `if (db[j].name > db[j+1].name)` не будет работать корректно.

А главное "но" - вам нужно **полностью** обменивать элементы массива, а не только одно поле, как у вас:

```
temp = db[j];
db[j].name = db[j+1].name;
db[j+1].name = temp;
```

Впрочем, тут вообще написан, простите, бред - `temp` имеет тип `int` - у вас точно `name` имеет тип `int`? судя по названию - нет. Но в любом случае вы присваиваете переменной `temp` не поле, а `db[j]`... Вобщем, разберитесь тут, и обменивайте **элементы**.

А то у вас получается примерно так - решили выстроить студентов по росту... Но при этом заставили зачетки положить на пол, где стоишь. Выстроили. А теперь каждый берет ту зачетку, которая лежит у его ног...

Ну, или при построении просто обменивались зачетками - кто ростом выше - зачетка идет в голову строя :)

Пусть у вас студенты с места на место переходя, носят зачетки :)

Весь остальной код на корректность не проверял, на беглый взгляд вроде более-менее нормально.

Comment: поле name имеет тип char

Comment: Ну не `char*`, надеюсь?

Comment: ... нет, не char*

Comment: Значит, использовать `>`  можно.