# Вывод на экран элементов индексного массива

Tags: c++, динамические-массивы, индексы

У меня есть индексный массив. Обязательно ли для него создавать структуру? И структура и функция создания индексного массива, расположены за пределами (не в) функции main. Как в функции main вывести на экран содержимое индексного массива? Индексный массив ещё нужно привязать к динамическому массиву db. Тип элементов поля name - char.

[Сортировка сложных структур методом пузырька](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/655471/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%B7%D1%8B%D1%80%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0)

Код:

```
void CreateIndArr(struct dataBase *stroka, struct IndArr *indarr) //ВРОДЕ ТЕ ПАРАМЕТРЫ? 
{   // i - кол-во записей в структуре (индекс итерации);  j - кол-во символов в ячейке 
    int t;    // номер индекса в массиве 
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        t=0;
        for (int j=0; j<32; j++)
        {
            if (stroka[i].name[j]==' ') {t++;}
            if (t==2)
            {
                indarr[i].dat = &stroka[i];
                indarr[i].fam[0]=stroka[i].name[j+1];
                indarr[i].fam[1]=stroka[i].name[j+2];
                indarr[i].fam[2]=stroka[i].name[j+3];
                t++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Оформите, пожалуйста, код в виде кода, а не снимка экрана.

Comment: Путем редактирования тела вопроса, а не комментария :)

Comment: Что за переменная `N`?

Comment: Это константа #define N 4. Означает, что количество записей в структуре dataBase равно 4.